# Cast nested []interface{} to []map[string]interface{}

Tags: json, go, parsing, recursion

My goal is to generate from a json a `map[string]interface` structure , where all nested `[]interface{}` are casted into `[]map[string]interface{}` . This is because we are using the module https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater to fill xlsx from json . And all the data is expected to be into a `map[string]interface{}` struct where all the nested `[]interface{}` are `[]map[string]interface`.

Having a json as an input like the following :

```js
{
    "totalAmount": 4,
    "subtotal": 4,
    "Vendors": [{
            "MethodOfTenders": [{
                "order": 1,
                "fees": 2
            }, {
                "order": 1,
                "fees": 2
            }],
            "subtotalFees": 4
        },
        {
            "MethodOfTenders": [{
                "order": 1,
                "fees": 2
            }, {
                "order": 1,
                "fees": 1
            }],
            "subtotalFees": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

When unmarshalling into an `map[string]interface{}` .I get the following struct :

```
map[string]interface{}:
  "totalAmount" : 4 interface{}(float64)
  "subtotal" : 4 interface{}(float64)
  "Vendors" : interface{}([]interface{})
       [0]: interface(map[string]interface{})
           "MethodOfTenders" : interface{}([]interface{})
                 [0] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64)
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
                 [1] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64),
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
           "subtotalFees" : 4 interface{}(float64)
       [1]: interface(map[string]interface{}) 
            "MethodOfTenders" : interface{}([]interface{})
                  [0] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64)
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
                 [1] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64),
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
           "subtotalFees" : 3 interface{}(float64)
```

After doing some parsing , ranging each []interface{} and creating a a []map[string]interface{} to store each one of the nested map[string]interface .

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoFI3.png]

I got the desired result where all []interfaces{} are []map[string]interface{}

```
 map[string]interface{}:
  "totalAmount" : 4 interface{}(float64)
  "subtotal" : 4 interface{}(float64)
  "Vendors" : interface{}([]map[string]interface{})
       [0]: interface(map[string]interface{})
           "MethodOfTenders" : interface{}([]map[string]interface{})
                 [0] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64)
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
                 [1] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64),
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
           "subtotalFees" : 4 interface{}(float64)
       [1]: interface(map[string]interface{}) 
            "MethodOfTenders" : interface{}([]map[string]interface{})
                  [0] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64)
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
                 [1] : interface(map[string]interface{})
                    "order" : 1 interface{}(float64),
                    "fees"  : 2 interface{}(float64)
           "subtotalFees" : 3 interface{}(float64)
```

Is there any way to walk al the map[string]interface recursively and change the []interfaces{} for []map[string]interface ?

EDIT:
Here the repository with the full template and json , currently working with the reflection approach .

[template and json repo](https://github.com/jcromanu/json_parser)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want your JSON to be parsed inside a struct? And may I ask why?

Comment: We are using https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater which requires the data to be into a []map[string]interface{} struct in order to fill an excel template with the data .

Comment: Can you share an example json and desired output?

Comment: @jcromanu: As I pointed out in my answer: you're incorrect in thinking go-xlsx-templater requires the data to be of type `[]map[string]interface{}`. The readme file gives an example where the full data is passed in as a `map[string]interface{}`. The templating engine handles slices/nested maps just fine, no cast/trickery required. Show the template, and check the one I suggested in my answer. a simple JSON marshal to a `map[string]interface{}` should work just fine

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the base struct must be a map[string] interface{} . But nested info must be []map[string] interface{} as the example shows .

Comment: @jcromanu and it is if you just unmarshal it into a `map[string]interface{}`. Look at the implementation of the module you're using, specifically [the `getRangeCtx` function](https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater/blob/master/xlst.go#L235). It contains type assertions to automatically convert any `interface{}` value to a slice, including `[]map[string]interface{}`. You don't have to do that yourself

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The trick is performed using reflection. Go down recursively and check the kind of values:

```
// "Casts" map values to the desired type recursively
func castMap(m map[string]any) map[string]any {
    for k := range m {
        switch reflect.ValueOf(m[k]).Kind() {
        case reflect.Map:
            mm, ok := m[k].(map[string]any)
            if !ok {
                panic(fmt.Errorf("Expected map[string]any, got %T", m[k]))
            }
            m[k] = castMap(mm)
        case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
            ma, ok := m[k].([]any)
            if !ok {
                panic(fmt.Errorf("Expected []any, got %T", m[k]))
            }
            m[k] = castArray(ma)
        default:
            // fmt.Printf("%s: %T, kind %v\n", k, m[k], reflect.ValueOf(m[k]).Kind())
            continue
        }
    }
    return m
}

// "Casts" slice elements to the desired types recursively
func castArray(a []any) []map[string]any {
    res := []map[string]any{}
    for i := range a {
        switch reflect.ValueOf(a[i]).Kind() {
        case reflect.Map:
            am, ok := a[i].(map[string]any)
            if !ok {
                panic(fmt.Errorf("Expected map[string]any, got %T", a[i]))
            }
            am = castMap(am)
            res = append(res, am)
        default:
            panic(fmt.Errorf("Expected map[string]any, got %T", a[i]))
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Full example with `main` is here: https://go.dev/play/p/MEQRe-f3dY1

It's output:

```
before: map[string]interface {}{"Vendors":[]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"MethodOfTenders":[]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"fees":2, "order":1}, map[string]interface {}{"fees":2, "order":1}}, "subtotalFees":4}, map[string]interface {}{"MethodOfTenders":[]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"fees":2, "order":1}, map[string]interface {}{"fees":1, "order":1}}, "subtotalFees":3}}, "subtotal":4, "totalAmount":4}
after: map[string]interface {}{"Vendors":[]map[string]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"MethodOfTenders":[]map[string]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"fees":2, "order":1}, map[string]interface {}{"fees":2, "order":1}}, "subtotalFees":4}, map[string]interface {}{"MethodOfTenders":[]map[string]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"fees":2, "order":1}, map[string]interface {}{"fees":1, "order":1}}, "subtotalFees":3}}, "subtotal":4, "totalAmount":4}
```

See? `"Vendors"` was `[]interface {}`, became `[]map[string]interface {}`
`"Vendors[].MethodOfTenders"` were `[]interface {}`, became `[]map[string]interface {}`

The functions panic if they see something unexpected. Feel free to modify them to returning `error` if needed.

**UPDATE**

Here is the same recursive algoritm using type assertions.

```
// "Casts" map values to the desired type recursively
func castMap(m map[string]any) map[string]any {
    for k := range m {
        mm, ok := m[k].(map[string]any)
        if ok {
            m[k] = castMap(mm)
            continue
        }
        ma, ok := m[k].([]any)
        if ok {
            m[k] = castArray(ma)
            continue
        }
    }
    return m
}

// "Casts" slice elements to the desired types recursively
func castArray(a []any) []map[string]any {
    res := []map[string]any{}
    for i := range a {
        am, ok := a[i].(map[string]any)
        if ok {
            am = castMap(am)
            res = append(res, am)
        } else {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("Expected map[string]any, got %T", a[i]))
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Full code https://go.dev/play/p/IbOhQqpisie

**BENCHMARK**

One of the commenters made a claim that `reflection is expensive`. This is not the case here:

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org/try/test
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
BenchmarkCastReflect-8        382574          2926 ns/op        2664 B/op         29 allocs/op
BenchmarkCastType-8           418257          2934 ns/op        2664 B/op         29 allocs/op
```

The benchmark is here: https://go.dev/play/p/Ro8PeVQy8kA

*Playground doesn't execute benchmarks. It should be run on a real CPU*

Comment: Does this implementation has a minimum go target version in order to work ?

Comment: @jcromanu The type name `any` is the synonym for `interface{}` since go1.18. If you need an older version, just replace `any` with `interface{}`. That's all. `ValueOf` and `Kind` are there from Go 1.

Comment: @jcromanu here is the version with `interface{}` type instead of `any`: https://go.dev/play/p/x1P0gGaQ9-f It is expected to work with any Go version. Tried with 1.19, 1.18, 1.16

Comment: There is absolutely no need for reflection here. A simple type assertion is all that is needed. Reflection is expensive, difficult to maintain, and error-prone. In fact, I'm pretty sure there's not even a need for any type assertions/casts at all for this particular use-case

Comment: @jcromanu This is terrible. type casts > reflection for a use case like this. This is needlessly complex and inefficient.

Comment: @PakUula would changing reflection to type assertions would be possible using this recursive approach ?

Comment: @jcromanu added casting using type assertions. Benchmark shows its performance is same compared to the reflection version

Comment: here a [`link`](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/HcfutSkJVoY) to blog for info about in which case reflection is slow

Comment: @jcromanu My answer includes a function that uses type casts, all you need to do is make it recursive. This is not a free code-generator site, you've been given all information needed to implement the solution. This site aims to be a Q&A formatted reference for others to find answers, too. You've instead marked the worst approach as being the correct one...

Comment: panic: Expected map[string]any, got map[interface {}]interface {} [recovered]

Answer (score 1):

## Update

So I've since noticed you added a link to a repo containing what you have so far. The template is weird (some of the values in there aren't part of your sample data). I've removed all fields except for the ones that were actually in the sample data JSON you have. As it turns out, the package you are using is quite rough around the edges (it does take care of type assertions in nested values, but not at the top level). I'd personally either fork the package and fix that issue, but in the mean while, if you know what fields you want to iterate over, I got it all to work in about 5 minutes with this:

```
var jsonMap map[string]interface{}
data := sampleData()
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &jsonMap)
if err != nil {
    panic("Final log")
}
ctx := jsonMap
v := jsonMap["Vendors"]
vs := v.([]interface{})
vendors := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0, len(vs))
for _, v := range vs {
    m := v.(map[string]interface{})
    vendors = append(vendors, m)
}
jsonMap["Vendors"] = vendors

doc := xlst.New()
err = doc.ReadTemplate("export_support_template.xlsx")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR OPENING THE TEMPLATE: ", err)
    panic("error opening template")
}
err = doc.Render(ctx)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR RENDERING THE TEMPLATE: ", err)
    panic("error rendering template")
}
err = doc.Save("report.xlsx")
```

As you can see, I just unmarshalled the data. I then focused on the `Vendors` key, cast it to a slice (`v.([]inteface{}`), created a new variable of type `[]map[string]interface{}`, and copied over the data casting the elements of the slice to maps in this simple loop:

```
for _, v := range vs {
    m := v.(map[string]interface{})
    vendors = append(vendors, m)
}
```

Then, I just reassigned the `Vendors` key in the original map (`ctx["Vendors"] = vendors`), and passed that in to the template. Less than 10 lines of code needed, and everything worked like a charm. No need for reflection, or any other magic. Just straightforward type casts. Without this, the package you're using does complain about the use of `range` on an `interface{}` type (instead of first checking to see if the key can be successfully cast to a `[]interface{}` first). I removed all other functions from your main file (except for the sample data one), ran `go build` and executed `./json_marshaller`. It churned out a correctly populated xlsx file no problem. Easy.

I'd still recommend you actually create a PR to the templater package so you don't have to handle this stuff yourself. It should be a fairly straightforward change, but for the time being: this approach works perfectly well.

---

## Include your template

Looking at the repository of the go-xlsx-templater, I don't really see why you'd need anything other than this:

```
data := map[string]interface{}
_ = json.Unmarshal(input, &data)
```

The reason why this is perfectly fine, is because go-xlsx-templater performs the type conversion of all `interface{}` values within this map already. It will traverse the map, and check if any of the values are of the type `[]interface{}`, it'll then iterate over this slice and check for `map[string]interface{}` values inside the slice. It's [all in the source code](https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater/blob/master/xlst.go#L235). Going by their own documentation, it should work just fine if your template looks somewhat like this:

```
| Total:              | {{ totalAmount }}  |
| Subtotal:           | {{ subtotal }}     |
|                     | Vendor subtotal    | fees                       | order                       |
| {{ range Vendors }} |
|                     |                    | {{ MethodsOfTender.Fees }} | {{ MethodsOfTender.order }} |
|                     | {{ subtotalFees }} |
| {{ end }}           |
```

You should end up with the spreadsheet being populated correctly:

```
| Total:    | 4               |      |       |
| Subtotal: | 4               |      |       |
|           | Vendor subtotal | fees | order |
|           |                 | 2    | 1     |
|           |                 | 2    | 1     |
|           | 4               |      |       |
|           |                 | 2    | 1     |
|           |                 | 1    | 1     |
|           | 3               |      |       |
```

Essentially, the data-set you're showing is no different to the example the repo gives in their very own **[main README file](https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater#prepare-templatexlsx-template)**. The context data itself contains nested maps, and a screenshot of a spreadsheet template showing how to use it. Putting it bluntly, I feel like your question is pretty much a case of RTFM...

Without your template, however, there's no way to be sure, so I'm leaving my initial answer in full below...

---

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you're looking for a way to use type assertions/casts to extract keys from a map of type `map[string]interface{}` and use the values of type `[]interface{}` as `[]map[string]interface{}`. In this particular example, you need the top level key `Vendors` to be accessible as `[]map[string]interface{}` (as opposed to `interface{}` or `[]interface{}`). If that's what you're looking for, you can do this quite easily:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
nested := map[string][]map[string]interface{}{} // subset of data that needs to be accessible as slices of maps
for k, v := range data {
    if s, ok := v.([]interface); ok {
        // this key is of type []interface, see if we can use it as slice of maps
        if mapS, err := sliceAnyToMap(s); err == nil {
            nested[k] = mapS
        } // handle error if needed
    }
}

func sliceAnyToMap(s []any) ([]map[string]interface{}, error) {
    ret := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0, len(s))
    for _, v := range s {
        if m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            ret = append(ret, m)
        } else {
            return nil, errors.New("slice contains non-map data")
        }
    }
    return ret, nil
}
```

With this, you'll end up with a variable called `nested` which will contain keys like `Vendors`, with the data accessible as a `[]map[string]interface{}`. This can be passed on to your templater to populate the spreadsheet with the vendors data.

### [Demo here](https://go.dev/play/p/KNI26kbXkfo)

Now, inside some of the `Vendors` key, there is some data which is in turn a a map, which still can't be accessed directly. Breaking up this `sliceAnyToMap` stuff into a function will make it easier to convert all data you need fairly easily.

---

Now, having said all this, I do personally think this is very much an X-Y problem. The data you've shown here looks to be of a very well defined structure. Rather than faffing around with `map[string]interface{}` and the like, it would be a whole lot easier to read, write, and maintain if you were to use actual types. Based on what you've included in your question, a couple of types like this would be all it takes:

```
type Data struct {
    Total    float64  `json:"totalAmount"`
    Subtotal float64  `json:"subtotal"`
    Vendors  []Vendor `json:"Vendors"`
}

type Vendor struct {
    MethodOfTenders []MOT   `json:"MethodOfTenders"`
    SubtotalFees    float64 `json:"subtotalFees"`
}

type MOT struct {
    Fees  float64 `json:"fees"`
    Order float64 `json:"order"`
}
```

With these types, you can quickly, and easily parse the given input into a format that is much, much easier to use further down the line:

```
data := Data{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
for _, vendor := range data.Vendors {
    fmt.Printf("Vendor subtotal fees: %f\n", vendor.SubtotalFees)
    for i, mot := range vendor.MethodOfTenders {
        fmt.Printf("MOT %d:\nOrder: %f\nFees: %f\n\n", i+1, mot.Order, mot.Fees)
    }
    fmt.Println("-----")
}
```

### [Demo here](https://go.dev/play/p/zaMYpAYylel)

Last couple of things I'm wondering is whether or not all numberic values *should* be `float64`. Sure, it makes sense for amounts and/or fees (assuming they're monetary values), but the `Order` field probably contains an order number, which I don't expect to be a value like 0.123.

Finally, if you need to pass this data on to a templater of sorts which expects a map, then it's a fairly trivial thing to do using the aforementioned types all the same. There's a couple of ways to do this. The easy way being:

```
func (d Data) ToMap() (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    raw, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    asMap := map[string]interface{}{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &asMap); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return asMap, nil
}
```

JSON marshalling is quick to implement, but it's a tad inefficient, so you if performance matters a lot, then you could spend a few minutes writing some methods like:

```
func (d Data) ToMap() map[string]interface{} {
    vendors := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0, len(d.Vendors))
    for _, v := range d.Vendors {
        vendors = append(vendors, v.ToMap())
    }
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "totalAmount": d.Total,
        "subtotal":    d.Subtotal,
        "Vendors":     vendors,
    }
}

func (v Vendor) ToMap() map[string]interface{} {
    mot := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0, len(v.MethodsOfTender))
    for _, m := range v.MethodsOfTender {
        mot = append(mot, m.ToMap())
    }
    return map[string]interface{
        "MethodsOfTender": mot,
        "subtotalFees":    v.SubtotalFees,
    }
}

func (m MOT) ToMap() map[string]interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "fees":  m.Fees,
        "order": m.Order,
    }
}
```

Then, turning your `Data` object into a map is as simple as:

```
dataMap := data.ToMap()
```

Comment: We are aiming for a generic way without knowing each one of the keys , from what I saw your method sliceAnyToMap only creates maps at one nested layer right ? We would need to be effective to an n number of levels .

Comment: @jcromanu the nested levels are, based on what I saw in the repo, handled by the package you're using. Then again, I believe I also mentioned that I created this `sliceToMap` function as a standalone function so you can more easily make it a recursive function. While iterating over the argument (`[]interface{}`), you can check if the elements in that slice are slices, and if so, recursively call the function. Same goes for those values that are of type `map[string]interface{}` -> iterate the map and call the function recursively where needed

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := `{
            "totalAmount": 4,
            "subtotal": 4,
            "Vendors": [{
                    "MethodOfTenders": [
                    {
                            "order": 1,
                            "fees": 2
                        }, {
                        "order": 1,
                        "fees": 2
                        }
                ],
                    "subtotalFees": 4
            },
            {
                    "MethodOfTenders": [
                    {
                        "order": 1,
                            "fees": 2
                        }, {
                            "order": 1,
                            "fees": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "subtotalFees": 3
                }
            ]
        }   
    `
    var data map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", data)
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/x9wJDGas21G)

When Unmarshal from json it is generating expected output which is required by [`go-xlsx-templater`](https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater)

**Note:** Created a fix for the issue stated in the question [`here`](https://github.com/ChandanChainani/go-xlsx-templater) raised [`PR`](https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater/pull/9). After the fix no conversion is required.

After applying the fix the remaining code with `sampleData()` function which is not included in the example

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "strings"

    xlst "github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater"
)

func main() {
    wd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    path := strings.Join([]string{wd, ""}, "")
    doc := xlst.New()
    err = doc.ReadTemplate(path + "/export_support_template.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR OPENING THE TEMPLATE: ", err)
        panic("error opening template")
    }

    var ctx map[string]interface{}
    data := sampleData()
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Final log")
    }

    err = doc.Render(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR RENDERING THE TEMPLATE: ", err)
        panic("error rendering template")
    }
    err = doc.Save(path + "/report.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR SAVING THE TEMPLATE: ", err)
        panic("error saving template")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unmarshalling creates []interface on the nested ítems even if the underlying value Is a map .

Comment: @jcromanu https://github.com/ivahaev/go-xlsx-templater handles internally the case for `[]interface{}` you don't have to do anything

Comment: @Chandan question has been updated with a link to a repo containing the template. I've quickly tried it out and it seems that `go-xlsx-templater` is a bit borked. A top-level `{{ range Key }}` seems to bypass the type casting one would expect to be performed, and just clunks out because of _"not expected context property for range"_. It shouldn't be too hard to fix the package itself (or find a better one), but top level keys currently need to be manually handled.

Comment: @jcromanu I have fix the issue here [`here`](https://github.com/ChandanChainani/go-xlsx-templater) after which conversion is not required updated the answer with the same info as well

Comment: @Chandan LOL, was thinking to PR a similar fix over the weekend... Ah well, OP seems convinced that reflection is the answer. No reasoning with some people